# Using angle bisector to prove a quadrilateral is concyclic.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, circles

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle with an obtuse angle $A$ and incentre $I$. Circles $ABI$ and $ACI$ intersect $BC$ again at $X$ and $Y$ respectively. The lines $AX$ and $BI$ meet at $P$, and the lines $AY$ and $CI$ meet at $Q$. Prove that $BCQP$ is cyclic.

I drew the diagram and saw that angle $AIB$ is equal to angle $AXB$

And angle $AIC$ is equal to angle $AYC$.

I tried making such pairs for the circle $BCQP$ but couldn't do so.

I tried using angle bisector and making some triangles congruent or similar but couldn't conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can see my diagram here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXwTS.png)

Looking in $(ABXI)$ we have $\angle BXA=\angle BIA=90^\circ+\angle C/2$. Thus, $\angle PXY=90^\circ-\angle C/2$.

Further, note that $\angle PIC=90^\circ+\angle A/2$ and looking in $(ACYI)$ we have \begin{align*}\angle YIQ&=\angle YAC=180^\circ-\angle C-\angle AYC= 180^\circ-\angle C-\angle AIC \\ &=180^\circ-\angle C-\angle(90^\circ+\angle B/2)=\angle A+\angle B/2-90^\circ.\end{align*}Therefore, $\angle PIY=\angle PIC-\angle YIQ=90+\angle C/2$ so $\angle PIY+\angle PXY=180^\circ$.

Thus,the points $X,Y,P,I$ lie on a circle and analogously, we may infer that $Q$ is on this circle too. Hence, $\angle IPQ=\angle IYQ=\angle ICA=\angle C/2$ but $\angle ICB=\angle C/2$ as well, hence $P,Q,B,C$ lie on the same circle.

Comment: Hi, I can see that $\angle BXA=\angle BIA=90^\circ+\angle C/2$. But how does that give us $\angle PXY=90^\circ-\angle C/2$?

Comment: Because $\angle PXY=180^\circ-\angle BXA=180^\circ-(90^\circ+\angle C/2)=90^\circ-\angle C/2$.

Comment: You have written "Therefore, $\angle PIQ=\angle PIC-\angle YIQ$" But aren't angle PIQ and PIC just the same? Maybe instead of PIQ, you wanted to write PIY?

Comment: Yes, I meant to write $\angle PIY$ thank you

Comment: I understood that X, P, I, Q, Y lie on the same circle. But not able to understand $\angle IPQ=\angle IYQ=\angle ICA=\angle C/2$?

Comment: First, we look in the circle determined by $X,Y,P,I,Q$ and thus $\angle IPQ=(\text{arc }IQ)/2=\angle IYQ$. Then, looking in the circle determined by $A,I,Y,C$ we have $\angle IYQ=(\text{arc }IA)/2=\angle ICA$. Finally, we have $\angle ICA=\angle C/2$ since $CI$ is a bisector.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer and your patient replies.

Comment: I understood "Hence, $\angle IPQ=\angle IYQ=\angle ICA=\angle C/2$ but $\angle ICB=\angle C/2$ as well". From this, how are we concluding that P,Q,B,C lie on the same circle?

Comment: Because $\angle IPQ=180^\circ-\angle QPB$ and of course $\angle ICB$ is the same thing as $\angle QCB$ so $\angle QPB+\angle QCB=180^\circ$ which implies $P,Q,B,C$ concyclic.

Comment: Thankyou, got it.